# detect changes in Angular forms with changeDetectionStrategy.onPush

Tags: angular, forms

So I need to detect form status change while I am using **changedetectionStrategy.onPush**
.
so the problem is:  if I add a new input to the form and it is empty and I delete it after form.status still shows that the form is invalid even though I deleted empty input. And because of it Save button is still disabled.
But when I press any other input form status changes .

I know it is because I have changeDetectionStrategy.onPush
When it is on default setting it works without a problem
So is there any other way to fix this other than leave changeDetection on default settigs?

Answer (score 0):

you can import `ChangeDetectorRef` in the constructor like the following

```
 constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }
```

and don't forget to import it like so :

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
```

and after that you can use the method `detectChanges` where you run the check for the form status  like the following :

```
 this.ref.detectChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

while using `changeDetectionStrategy.onPush` strategy you told angular to stop running their default change detection cycle. so after your changes, you have to force angular to run their change detection cycle.

> @Component({...,
> changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
> })

you have 2 ways to do this. first import and declare **ChangeDetectorRef**

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

1. reattach or continue angular change detection cycle as normal. this will check all changes in the component DOM tree.
   `this.cd.reattach();`
2. Manually fire change detection cycle on your wish. it will verify DOM even not a single entity change. `this.cd.detectChanges();`